# Solving three-variable nonlinear equation systems

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

A physical problem which I've been studying leads to the following nonlinear equation system to be solved:
$$\alpha\cdot79\cdot A_1 +(1-\alpha)\cdot 1025 \cdot B_1 = C_{11}$$
$$\alpha\cdot145\cdot A_1 +(1-\alpha)\cdot 696 \cdot B_1 = C_{12}$$
$$\alpha\cdot12\cdot A_1 +(1-\alpha)\cdot 1578 \cdot B_1 = C_{13}$$
In these equations, $\alpha$ is an UNKNOWN universal coefficient, $A_1$ and $B_1$ are UNKNOWN variables to be obtained, and $C_{11}, C_{12}, C_{13}$ are KNOWN constants obtained from experiments. In total, we have 9 pairs of $A$ and $B$ to be obtained the corresponding experimental results $C$, for example, the pair of $A_2$ and $B_2$ should hold the following relationship with $C$: 
$$\alpha\cdot79\cdot A_2 +(1-\alpha)\cdot 1025 \cdot B_2 = C_{21}$$
$$\alpha\cdot145\cdot A_2 +(1-\alpha)\cdot 696 \cdot B_2 = C_{22}$$
$$\alpha\cdot12\cdot A_2 +(1-\alpha)\cdot 1578 \cdot B_2 = C_{23}$$
and the same for the other $A_n, B_n$ and $C$. But remember, the coefficient $\alpha$ is unknown. Therefore in total there are $2 \times 9 +1 = 19$ coefficients to be obtained from 27 equations.
My question is, what is the best algorithm to obtain the best solution to both the universal coefficient $\alpha$ and the pairs of $A,B$ please? Thank you very much!

Comment: Are there always the same $79,1025,145,696,12,1578$ terms ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks for you reply. Yes they are, the coefficients and the $\alpha$ are always the same for all different A and B pairs, but the constants on the right hand sides of the equations will be different, therefore the solutions to A and B are expected to be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two equations suffice to determine $\alpha A_1$ and $(1-\alpha) B_1$.
The third equation is either true or false with those values of $\alpha A_1$ and $(1-\alpha) B_1$, so (depending on how $C_{13}$ relates to $C_{11}$ and $C_{12}$) either it makes the system inconsistent or it doesn't add any new information.
Similarly for the other $\alpha A_i$ and $(1-\alpha) B_i$.  If those are all the constraints, you can choose $\alpha$ arbitrarily (as long as it's not  $0$ or $1$), and then find $A_i$ and $B_i$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So does it mean there is no way that I can find a unique solution for $\alpha$ and $A_i-B_i$ pair as a direct solution to the equations please? I was sort of expecting that, but is there a way to find an $\alpha$ that fits all the equations best, e.g. gives the least square error etc. ?

Comment: After a second thought, I think I'm gonna disagree with your comment. The third equation should in effect still provide a constraint to the solution. If I choose a random $\alpha$ and the first two equations should of course give me a unique pair of $A_i$ and $B_i$, which would almost certainly not satisfy the third one. Only a certain value of $\alpha$ can give the pair that make the residual of all three equations smallest. (Just imagine using $\alpha$, $A_i$-$B_i$ to generate $C$, and then to inversely use the generated $C$ to obtain the original variables. )

Comment: The three equations depend only on $\alpha A_1$ and $(1-\alpha) B_1$.  A certain pair of values of $\alpha A_1$ and $(1-\alpha) B_1$ makes the residual smallest.  Let's suppose it's $\alpha A_1 = \gamma_1$ and $(1-\alpha) B_1 = \delta_1$.  Choose any $\alpha$ as long as it's not $0$ or $1$, and you can take $A_1 = \gamma_1/\alpha$ and $B_1 = \delta_1/(1-\alpha_1)$ to realize these.

Comment: Thanks I see! So no way to decouple $\alpha$ from $A_i$ and $B_i$ based on these equations then?